# Replace an image with an uploaded one

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, sql

I'm having a bit of trouble solving an issue with imaging uploading. I'm using an html file upload form with a jquery function that checks the file type of the image being selected. What I want to do is replace the current image on a web site page with whatever the user decides to upload. However, I cannot find a way to get the full image source path from the upload--I always get a fake path, which doesn't work for what I want to do. Do I really need to create a database for images if I want to do this, or is there some other way? I can't use PHP/MySQL code--only ASP.NET, C#, and SQL/SQL Express.

Here is the code I have so far, which works except I can't successfully replace the default image (which has name and id of "logo) with an uploaded one since I don't get the full path from the uploader. Any suggestions would be very helpful! Thanks in advance!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Image Swap Widget Testing</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .myWebForm{
            border: 4px solid grey;
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            padding: 10px;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: small;
        }
    </style>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('INPUT[type="file"]').change(function () {
                    var ext = this.value.match(/\.(.+)$/)[1];
                    switch (ext) {
                        case 'jpg':
                        case 'jpeg':
                        case 'png':
                        case 'gif':
                        case 'bmp':
                            $('#uploading').attr('disabled', false);
                            $('#logo').attr("src", $('#uploading').val());
                            alert('image approved!');
                            alert($('img').attr('src'));
                            alert($('img')[0].src);
                            alert($('#uploading').val(img.src));
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert('This is not an allowed file type.');
                        this.value = '';
                    }
                });

                $('#addButton').click(function (){
                    //alert('Add Image Button was clicked');

                    //var newImgSrc = getSrc($('#uploading').val());
                    //$('#logo').attr("src", newImgSrc);
                    //alert($('#logo').attr("src"));
                    //alert($('#uploading').val());

                });
            });

    </script>
    </head>

    <body>  

    <img src="Lighthouse.jpg" name="logo" alt="logo" id="logo" width="200" />

    <br/>

    <form name="myWebForm" class="myWebForm" action="#" method="post">
        <h3>Change Default Logo</h3>
            <input type="file" name="uploadField" id="uploading" />
        <p><b>Allow extensions:</b> .png, .bmp, .jpg, .jepg, .gif<p>
        <p><b>Dimensions:</b> 50px x 80px<p>
        <input type="button" name="addButton" id ="addButton" class="addButton" value="+ Add" />
        <input type="button" name="cancelButton" id ="cancelButton" class="cancelButton" value="X Cancel" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can always use the FileSystem API.  First, our input:

```
<input type="file" id="MyImage" />
```

Listen for the change and grab the file:

```
document.getElementById('MyImage').onchange = function(e) {
    // Get the first file in the FileList object
    var imageFile = this.files[0];
    // get a local URL representation of the image blob
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(imageFile);
    // Now use your newly created URL!
    someImageTag.src = url;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: No problem!  I'm glad I could help.  Was it actually the answer?  If so, please mark this as answered but, if not, I'm happy I could point you in the right direction :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use iframe transport you can get the path from iframe when it's loaded.

```
<script>
$('#upload-frame').load(function(e) {
    $('img').attr('src', $(this).contents().find('body').html());
});
</script>
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"
      id="upload-form" target="upload-frame">
  <input type="file" name="uploadField" id="uploading" />
  <input type="submit" value="upload"/>
</form>
<iframe id="upload-frame" name="upload-frame"></iframe>
```

on server you can do something like:

```
$info = pathinfo(basename($_FILES['image']['name']));
$ext = strtolower($info['extension']);
if (in_array($ext, array('png', 'jpg', 'gif', 'bmp'))) {
    $path = 'SOME/PATH/filename.' . $ext;
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
        echo $path;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MarcelKorpel sorry I don't know Asp.Net but I'm sure that you can do the same. Just search for `upload asp.net`